# I'm a noob, but Can i write a c++ program with a gui and have it run on both visual studio 2010 express and the terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, user-interface, ubuntu

I'm pretty new to c++ and am not quite sure what i am doing. I want to implement a supermarket , with a gui, and have it work on both ubuntu and windows. I read about downloading tool kits for it, but I dont know how involved that is or if there is a simpler way to do it. I've never done a project like this in c++ (java is my strong suit) and want to make sure i am not going over my head. If tool kits are the way to go, which one? how do i do it? and do i have to download it on both OS's. Thanks for the help, its really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to make your life harder using C++ for supermarket app instead of Java (which is your "strong suit")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c++ doesn't include any facilities for a gui so you'll either have to use what comes with the platform or a 3rd party library that exists for both platforms. CLearly if you want to write code that will work on both you own't want to use the windows / ubuntu native api's so I'd suggest looking into something like [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/product/) which seems to be a widely used cross platform gui toolkit for c++

Answer (score 1):

You can [download Qt](http://qt-project.org/downloads). It comes with a lot of sample code and documentation.

Comment: do i need to download it on both windows and ubuntu or is it just a header file i can copy and paste?

Comment: you will not have to write different code for both platforms but will have to compile it on both. Therefore you'll have to download sdks and compilers on both platforms and copy pasting binaries won't work. I'm not sure if you can cross compile Qt code on Ubuntu for Windows but you can start writing code for one platform first..

Answer (score 0):

You should write your gui using some cross platform library, such as QT. Qmake will make for you a makefile suitable for the different platforms you want to use.